# Find a word in a text file and assign it to a variable in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, find, cpu-word

I am trying to search a txt file for a word with 60 seconds intervals (because txt file's content changes over time) and if this word is found, searching will be stopped and execute some codes.
I used below code to find the word but I can not figure out how to assign it to a variable.

```
>nul find "SUCCESS" C:\usr\new.txt && (
  echo OK
) || (
  echo FAILED
)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really need here to achieve your goals is a holding loop, timeout & findstr, using a successful result to break the loop.

```bat
    @Echo Off
rem // define and qualify search file path
    Set "Searchee=%~1"
    If not exist "%Searchee%" (Echo/File not located & Exit /B)
rem // holding loop
:Hold
    (Type "%Searchee%" | (Findstr /L "SUCCESS")) >Nul 2> Nul && Goto :Act
    Timeout 60 >Nul
Goto :Hold
:Act
    Echo/String Located
rem // insert commands to be enacted
```